# How to run the cucumber test parallelly_Junit/TestNg

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

Iam using cucumber test with testng , iam planning to run the test parallely.I have previous experience by using testng framework and executed parallely , how can i achieve the same without using mavensurfire plugin (pom.xml)

Configuration which i have,

> Cucumber JVM,TestNGCucumberRunner.java file to trigger the feature file

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what you ask, but using jUnit. With testNG is the same, but you have tu change the dependency in the pom.xml.

Here is a link in which explain that better
http://www.opencredo.com/2013/07/02/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/

and here is the project of github, that can help you as a example.
https://github.com/tristanmccarthy/Cucumber-JVM-Parallel/

Comment: Thanks Hugo , i have gradle not maven , can you please tell me some other solution.

Comment: I think that it could be possible to cast the example proyect from maven to gradle, but i do not know it exactily.