# Can I use Cucumber with Selenium Grid to run the scripts on different node at the same time?

Tags: ui-automation, selenium-grid, cucumber-java, selenium-grid2, parallel-execution

I have searched for same but faced with failure.
Is there any other tool which can be utilised effectively to run the scripts on multiple node?

Answer (score 0):

Posible duplicate of : [How to execute cucumber test cases in parallel using Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424477/how-to-execute-cucumber-test-cases-in-parallel-using-grid)

For me, TestNG is good to parallelize your tests and here is a question and answer about it : 
[How to run the cucumber test parallelly_Junit/TestNg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239531/how-to-run-the-cucumber-test-parallelly-junit-testng)

Comment: Yes. It is possible with testng. But I am looking for cucumber.

Comment: Yes, I am also giving solution for cucumber. Cucumber is framework for writing test and you should implement other libraries for running that framework parallelized. There is no way to do that with only cucumber @JitendraPisal

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber 4 provides native support to run scenarios in paralllel. You dont need cucumber -Jvm.
you have to put number of threads in the runner file (--thread = 2) and just pass the selenium hub to your selenium driver during initialization.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific on how to add --thread = 2 to the runner?